# 3 колонны на flexbox

Tags: html, css, html5, flexbox, scss

Никак не получается сверстать 3 колонны с иконкой, тайтлом и инфой, выручайте

```css
.container {
  width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thrd-screen {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.fast-delivery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scam-icon {
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 140px;
}

.scam-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000000;
}

.scam-descrp {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 413px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div class="fast-delivery">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/restaurants.svg" alt="" class="scam-icon">
  <h3 class="scam-title">Швидка доставка</h3>
  <p class="scam-descrp">Наш плюс — швидкість. Замовте доставку в межах міста і ми все доставимо за лічені хвилини. Beatae sed non incidunt dolorum iusto et.</p>
</div>
<div class="best-restornts">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/delivery.svg" alt="" class="scam-icon">
  <h3 class="scam-title">Найкращі ресторани вашого міста </h3>
  <p class="scam-descrp">На нашому сайті — величезний вибір ресторанів. Замовте свою улюблену їжу або дізнайтеся, про нові ресторани поруч із вами!</p>
</div>
<div class="exp-couriers">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/groceries.svg" alt="" class="scam-icon">
  <h3 class="scam-title">Освідчені кур’єри</h3>
  <p class="scam-descrp">Наші кур’єри ніколи не пошкодять ваше замовлення, не затримають термін доставки, а навіть якщо таке й станеться - ми повернемо вам до 100% від ціни</p>
</div>
<button class="order-button center">Замовити доставку!</button>
```

Результат должен получиться вот такой:
[image: Вот как выглядит макет]

upd. Simon скинул ссылку на классную информацию, я понял наконец-то как работает флексбокс и решил проблему сам, а KopteLove написал очень профессиональный код, который так же полностью решает проблему, ещё и адаптивнено. Спасибо!

Comment: [Разбираемся с обёртыванием Flex элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items)

Comment: Ну и наверное в целом имеет смысл сделать Ваши колонки более универсальными. Зачем каждой из колонок свой уникальный класс, они же по-сути одинаковые. Сделайте ряд, назовите его row, а внутрь уже добавьте колонки c классом column например, чтобы в дальнейшем это можно было использовать еще где-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.advantage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.advantage__block {
  max-width: calc(100% - 33%);
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.advantage__row {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.advantage__icon {
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 140px;
}

.advantage__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.advantage__description {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
}

.advantage__btn {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff6c4e;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .advantage__row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="advantage">
    <div class="advantage__row">
      <div class="advantage__block">
        <img class="advantage__icon" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/restaurants.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="advantage__title">Швидка доставка</h3>
        <p class="advantage__description">Наш плюс — швидкість. Замовте доставку в межах міста і ми все доставимо за лічені хвилини. Beatae sed non incidunt dolorum iusto et.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="advantage__block">
        <img class="advantage__icon" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/delivery.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="advantage__title">Найкращі ресторани вашого міста </h3>
        <p class="advantage__description">На нашому сайті — величезний вибір ресторанів. Замовте свою улюблену їжу або дізнайтеся, про нові ресторани поруч із вами!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="advantage__block">
        <img class="advantage__icon" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/glovoapp/image/fetch//q_auto/https://glovoapp.com/images/why-glovo/groceries.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="advantage__title">Освідчені кур’єри</h3>
        <p class="advantage__description">Наші кур’єри ніколи не пошкодять ваше замовлення, не затримають термін доставки, а навіть якщо таке й станеться - ми повернемо вам до 100% від ціни</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="advantage__btn">Замовити доставку!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Simon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211900/simon) хороший совет дал про flex, это просто !

Comment: Если обратить внимание, то три колонки разной ширины :)